# How do I show vertex colors in Edit Mode in 2.9?

Tags: 3d-view, vertex-colors

I just moved from Blender 2.79 to 2.9 (so this may also apply to 2.8)…

How can I view vertex colors when I'm in Edit Mode?

I have the viewport set to Solid in viewport settings.

Everything is fine in Object Mode, but as soon as I switch to Edit Mode the object turns black.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember how 2.79 handled it, and I deleted it so I can't check. How do you view them in 2.79?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett it just worked in 2.79. If you had vertex color showing in Solid in Object Mode, they still showed in Edit Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug and also already on the list to be fixed in 2.90.1
https://developer.blender.org/T80396

Comment: Ah, thank you for this!